# Should I check existence before saving, or just catch an exception on a duplicate key violation?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, soap

**Which way to prevent duplicate transactions works faster?** I have a SOAP-based gateway, which receives the following request:

```
  <soap:Body>
    <ProcessItem>
      <Item>
        <ItemType>int</ItemType>
        <ItemName>string</ItemName>
      </Item>
    </ProcessItem>
  </soap:Body>
```

Now I must not save an item with the same name and type values.  I have two options:

1. Do validation, thus preventing duplication programmatically--for example:

   ```
       if (!ItemReposioty.Exists(concreteItem))
       {
           ItemRepository.Save(concreteItem);
       }
       else
       {
           return DuplicateStatus(); 
       }
   ```
2. Use a unique constraint or index in a MS SQL Server table, making field type and name unique, thus preventing duplication at the database level.

   ```
   try 
   {
       ItemRepository.Save(newItem); 
   } 
   catch (SqlException e) 
   {
       return DuplicateStatus(); 
   }
   ```

Which would you do?

Comment: for me, it will be `BOTH` . `2` to ensure i don't have bad data, `1` to ensure i handle the error gracefully

Comment: i am gonna create an indexed  additional table  with one column for  saving  hash of item name and type. then apply both points 1 and 2 ( preventing  duplication programmatically and using embedded ms sql validation). thank all of you for your answer

Comment: @Z.R.T. You're just wasting time/space/cycles. You **must** create the constraint on the table anyways - which means the dbms will still evaluate the constraint during inserts/updates. And to be honest, I can't imagine a transaction table having this constraint at all. Transactions typically have the same characteristics over time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly,  I suppose in most cases, the latter way could be faster in that it doesn't need to do two database calls.

I would choose the former way, although I would certainly set up the right database-side constraints as well.  I would presume (though not know for sure) that the ORM or other code behind the operations noted could execute this in an efficient way--that is, I'd expect the existence check to be significantly faster than the write operation.  Also, trips to a database over the LAN are fast compared to the overall latency of a HTTP request, and so figuring out how to combine two database operations into one may be naive optimization.

In the latter case, you need to ensure that the SqlException that results is due to a duplicate key violation--other SqlExceptions could possibly happen for other reasons, and you likely don't want to handle them in the same way.

To make the former solution more robust, you may wish to execute both within a transaction so that any locks from the first query might be retained and the update would happen atomically with the existence check.

Answer (score 1):

Putting it on the database side is the best way.  What if two instances of your code are running at the same time?  You can still potentially get duplicates.

And, if another process is created in the future that updates the database, bypassing your code, it may not check for duplicates.

Putting the unique index on the database ensures that duplicates can't happen.  You can still check for duplicates before attempting an insert, but the database should have the final say.